# PYTHON: How can I add +1 to a number in a file (txt.)

Tags: python

Okay so, I'm trying to make this little nifty auction program (for habbo if you've played it, but that's irrelevant.) Essentially, I have gotten pretty far with it, but my main goal is to be able to view Items (including their IDs for easy access) and to create new Items if I want.
Currently viewing items works fine, yet I'm struggling with the second goal, adding items.

I've used a bunch of different methods i've found on the internet, but none really seem to give the desired effect. I want to have a specific text document ("ID.txt") which simply starts at "0" and then each time my program is about to add an item, it adds 1 to that number in the file, so that I can call on it and give a brand new ID. So far each attempt I have it has done things like add [1] to the answer, instead of adding 1 itself.

```
import sys
import time
def choice1():
    print("#####################################################")
    print("Auction log opening")
    dotDot = "..."
    for char in dotDot:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    print("")
    print("1 - Choose an item ID")
    print("2 - Add an item")
    print("3 - Return to start")

    choices = input("Please make your choice. ")
    if choices == "1" and "#1" and "one":
        itemID = input("Enter item ID: ")
        if itemID == "#0001":
            aLog = open("auctionlist.txt")
            lines = aLog.readlines()
            print("#####################################################")
            print("")
            print(lines[0])
            print(lines[1])
            print(lines[2])
            print(lines[3])
            print("")
            print("#####################################################")
        elif itemID == "#0002":
            aLog = open("auctionlist.txt")
            lines = aLog.readlines()
            print("#####################################################")
            print("")
            print(lines[4])
            print(lines[5])
            print(lines[6])
            print(lines[7])
            print("")
            print("#####################################################")
    elif choices == "2" and "#2" and "two":
##        itemName = input("What's the item's name? ")
##        itemBought = input("Item buy price? ")
##        itemAvg = input("Item average? ")
##        itemSell = input("Target sell price? ")

        ID = open("ID.txt", "r+")
        content = ID.readlines()
        content[0] = content[0]+"1"
        ID.write(str(content))
        ID.close()

print("#####################################################")
print("Title: Auction House v0.1")
print("Author: Alasdair Cowie")
print("Date: 08/07/15")
print("#####################################################")
print("1 - Open the auction log.")
print("2 - Open the copy/paste log.")
print("3 - Exit the program")
oneTwoThree = input("Please make your choice. ")
if oneTwoThree == "1" and "one" and "#1" and "One":
    choice1()
```

Comment: Sorry if this is very vague, but I can explain in more detail if needed.

Comment: `content[0] = content[0]+"1"` Uh, you're adding strings to strings. What about `content[0] = str(int(content[0])+1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file and read its contents:

```
with open(filePath) as idFile:
  idString = idFile.read()
```

Convert the string to an int:

```
idNumber = int(idString)
```

Increase the number:

```
idNumber += 1
```

And write back that number:

```
with open(filePath, 'w') as idFile:
  idFile.write('%d' % idNumber)
```

That's it.

Comment: Could you add this to the format of my current code? I'm still doing this at GCSE level and have no idea how to fit it in, sorry x]

Comment: Thanks alot, this worked perfectly and now I can continue with the code. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could use a replace method, and increment in your code,
you would search for i-1 and replace it with i or something similar.

```
print ("Text to search for:i-1")
textToSearch = input( "> " ) 

print ("Text to replace it with:i")
textToReplace = input( "> " )

print ("File to perform Search-Replace on:")
fileToSearch  = input( "> " )
fileToSearch = 'D:\dummy1.txt'

tempFile = open( fileToSearch, 'r+' )

for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
    if textToSearch in line :
        print('Match Found')
    else:
        print('Match Not Found!!')
    tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
tempFile.close()


input( '\n\n Press Enter to exit...' )
```